# Align (center) header row in table

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment, tabu, multicolumn

I use `@{\hskip 50pt}` to separate columns in my table. The problem which arises is that I add this extra space after a `multicolumn`. This also moves the header row so that it is no longer centred. Is there any easy way to recenter the header name `MC`? I thought about just adding some extra whitespace after it to move it but maybe there is a better way of doing it. However, I don't want to use X columns or a different table environment to achieve that. It took me 5 days now to add everything to the tables and to align and stretch them properly as I want them to be. Apparently, this is only a very simple example not containing all of the other things I have in my tables but I think the problem is still clear and I am sure it only depends on the `multicolumn` and extra space issue:

```
\documentclass[10pt,DIV=12,a4paper,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tabu}      
\usepackage{multicol}  
\usepackage{multirow}  

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{tabu}{rr@{\hskip 50pt}rr@{\hskip 50pt}r}

\multicolumn{2}{c}{MC} & bla\\

asdasdsad & asdasdada & adasdddddddd \\
asdasdsad & asdasdada & adasdddddddd \\
asdasdsad & asdasdada & adasdddddddd \\

\end{tabu}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just write `c@{\hspace{50pt}}` as the second argument to `\multicolumn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `\multicolumn{<number>}{<spec>}{<text>}` the `<spec>` substitutes the whole block of the `tabular` column specifications and the intercolumn material belongs the the *preceding* column.

Exception: the material before the first column belongs to the first column.

So you have to respecify the intercolumn material if it's not the default; it would be just the same if you had rules instead of `@{...}`.

So you have to do

```
\begin{tabu}{rr@{\hspace{50pt}}rr@{\hspace{50pt}}r}

\multicolumn{2}{c@{\hspace{50pt}}}{MC} & bla\\

asdasdsad & asdasdada & adasdddddddd \\
asdasdsad & asdasdada & adasdddddddd \\
asdasdsad & asdasdada & adasdddddddd \\

\end{tabu}
```

and the result will be what you want.

Note that `\hspace{...}` is preferable to `\hskip...`

[image]

There's no way to do it automatically, as intercolumn material can be almost anything. Or, if there's a way, it's surely complicated, because it has to deal with many internals of `tabular` (and of `tabu`, as you use this one).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great example. Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

This will recenter your MC header.

```
\multicolumn{2}{c@{\hskip 50pt}}{MC} & bla\\
```

If your extra space is uniform, you can define a new column type, say `C`, for ease of use:

```
\newcolumntype{C}{c@{\hskip 50pt}}
% ...
\multicolumn{2}{C}{MC} & bla\\
```

Comment: thanks for your solution even though it is the same as provided by egreg. Just means it's a good way of doing it :) thanks!