# Centering table header with \multicolumn and intercolumn space

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, pdftex, columns

[A previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97172) directs that, when using `\multicolumn` in a tabular, subsequent intercolumn space added in the tabular column spec should be repeated in the `\multicolumn` column spec. However, this does not always work for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{~~}r@{~~}r@{\hspace{10pt}}r@{\hspace{10pt}}r@{}}
\hline
configuration & \multicolumn{1}{c@{~~}}{$M$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c@{~~}}{$w$} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{\hspace{10pt}}}{$x$} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{\hspace{10pt}}}{$y$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{H} \\
base model  & 5 & \multicolumn{1}{c@{~~}}{$w$} & 00000 & $y$ & 00000 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table with misaligned column header]

Note that the *x* is not quite centered. Any suggestions?

Comment: The third column could be completely simplified to `c` in the header *without* the `\multicolumn`s. However, your minimal example may have been over-simplified.

Comment: @Werner: Yes, I actually want to have more rows such that all columns but the first are right-aligned.

Answer (score 3):

Include the column spacing as part of the *cell* contents, not the column specification:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Original table:

\begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{~~}r@{~~}r@{\hspace{10pt}}r@{\hspace{10pt}}r@{}}
  \hline
  configuration & \multicolumn{1}{c@{~~}}{$M$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c@{~~}}{$w$} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{\hspace{10pt}}}{$x$} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{\hspace{10pt}}}{$y$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{H} \\
  base model  & 5 & \multicolumn{1}{c@{~~}}{$w$} & 00000 & $y$ & 00000 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Modified table:

\begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{~~}c@{~~}r@{\hspace{10pt}}r@{\hspace{10pt}}r@{}}
  \hline
  configuration & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$M$} & $w$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$x$\hspace*{10pt}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$y$\hspace*{10pt}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{H} \\
  base model  & 5 & $w$ & 00000 & 11111 & 00000 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```